# React-router: `<Link to=...>` does't trigger navigation change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got code similar to following:

```
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Here is content:</h1>
        {this.props.children}
        <Link to="/Welcome">Welcome</Link> |
        <Link to="/Login">Login</Link>
        <a href="/">REFERENCE LINK</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>No hejaaaa - welcome</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>No hejaaaa - Login</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="Welcome" component={Welcome}/>
      <Route path="Login" component={Login}/>
      <Route path="*" component={Welcome}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

// init file:
var RouterContext = ReactRouter.RouterContext
var match = ReactRouter.match

match({
  routes: Routes,
  location: document.location.pathname
}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />, document.querySelector('#app'));
});
```

Markup is generated correctly, but the problem is: Clicking in Links doesn't work at all.
I am doing something wrong?

My libs:

- "react": "0.14.7",
- "react-dom": "0.14.7",
- "react-router": "2.0.0"

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp3gzott/ (same code but babelified)

Comment: ps. I am using RouterContext because of server-side rendering. When doing simple`reactDOM.render(<Routes>, document.querySelector('#app'))`, react says: markup isn't equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in react-router documentation. According to [Server Rendering Guide](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md):

- In back end set:

> ```
> match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
>   renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />
> })
> ```

*Notice `RouterContext` instead of `Router` and lack of `history` field in `match` params*

- In front-end:

> ```
> match({ history, routes }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
>   ReactDOM.render(<Router {...renderProps} />, mountNode)
> })
> ```

*Notice lack of `location` param for `match`*

- In routes file:

  export `<Route` instead of `<Router`

---

Error `React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid.` is not showing up again.

Links are working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

`match()` is a Server side rendering construct, its intentional static, because on the server you only ever respond to a single route at a time. On the client you want to actually render a Router component

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    { Routes }
  </Router>
), document.querySelector('#app'))
```

Your, markup mismatch is probably due to a different issue, and you might want to check out one of the many "universal react" starters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately in combination with server-side rendering, `match` is necessary in both: back-end and front-end rendering.

Comment: hmm then that is certainly a new addition to the API, we don't do that at all on the client with SSR. Glad you got it working though